# Using SSIS I need to format data from excel into a flat file

Tags: excel, formatting, ssis, flat-file

I am trying to export data from an excel spreadsheet and insert it into a flat file, which is no problem. The problem is I need to have the data formatted in a certain way and I cannot do it manually as it is 36000+ records. I can create a flat file that gets formatted like so:

```
60|0006365290100989402|0.00|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

But I need it to be formatted like this:

```
60|0006365290100989402|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000|+00000000000000000
```

Any one know how or can point me in the right direction? The fields need to be a certain length, remove points(.) and add a + symbol at the beginning. I have tried using the 'Character Map' but with no luck.

Comment: You don't actually say how you are reading and exporting the data but assuming you are using a data flow then you will need to add a transformation step and convert the numbers into formatted text before outputting them.

Comment: Yes I am using a data flow. But how and which transformation step do I use? And can I specify the formatted text to appear in my desired format when outputted? @Ciarán

Comment: did you tried using derived column transformation to add 0 and cast to string?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have exported your data, use [NimbleText](http://www.nimbletext.com/home) to format it how you would like it.

Comment: Is it supposed to be SO slow?! I cant even type in the 'Substitute using this pattern' section without getting frustrated. 1 charecter every 5 seconds!. To use the command prompt part, which may work better, you need to purchase a licence. Anyone know what that means... "Purchase a licence'??? Lol. A colleague told me its probably best to write a SQL proc to format the data into a table, then using SSIS export that to  a flat file.